# How to make a listview and add populate it?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm new to windows phone 8 development and I can't find a way to add a listview control and populate it with items.

Could someone help me a lil.bit?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListBox structure is similiar to ListView.You just try this.If you don't know MVVM architecture, try to learn the basics of that.

```
<ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MasterTemplate}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding ItemLists}"  
         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The above shows the view.In the viewmodel,you can just declare a observablecollection like this.

```
public ObservableCollection<ProductModel> ItemLists{get;set;}
```

Then initialize the list like this,

```
ItemLists=new ObservableCollection<ProductModel>();
```

Then add elements to list and it will automatically display in the view because of binding.

```
private void addProducts()
{
  for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
     ItemLists.Add(new ProductModel{Name="Product"});
  }
}
```

This is the simple example.In the productmodel,you just declare the name property.

```
private string name;

public string Name
{
  get{return name;}
  set
  {
    name=value;
    OnPropertyChanged("Name");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) control in windows phone

A Simple ListBox looks like this(though it can be much more complex with [DataBinding](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Listbox_handling_in_Windows_Phone) etc).

```
<ListBox >
    <ListBoxItem Content="Item 1" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Item 2" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Item 3" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Item 4" />
</ListBox>
```